# Adding subqueries when one is null

Tags: mysql, sum, subquery

```
SELECT (select sum(furniture.furniture_sales)
            from furniture
            where cp.userid = furniture.userid) + 
        (select sum(electronics.electronic_sales)
            from electronics
            where cp.userid = electronics.userid) as total  
FROM customer_profile cp
```

Basically, if the userid doesn't exist in either furniture or electronics, then 'hold' will return as NULL. What can i do, so that 'total' will return a value instead of NULL?

Comment: use `ifnull()` ? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

Comment: Yup ifnull did the trick